# Perform data manipulations to SQL SERVER i got Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

Tags: java, jdbc

I have create table in sql server and assign DNS to it. I using window 8 and jdk 1.7.0.
My program compile successfully but when i try data manipulation to SQL SERVER then i got a exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver
```

Here is my java code:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MyDNS","","");
            Object obj=ae.getSource();
            if(obj==bins)
            {
                PreparedStatement pstat=con.prepareStatement("insert toys values(?,?,?)");
                pstat.setString(1,tid.getText());
                pstat.setString(2,tname.getText());
                pstat.setDouble(3,Double.parseDouble(trate.getText()));
                pstat.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Record Inserted");
            }
            else if(obj==bdel)
            {
                PreparedStatement pstat=con.prepareStatement("delete toys where ctoyid=?");
                pstat.setString(1,tid.getText());
                pstat.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Record Deleted");
            }
            else if(obj==bupd)
            {
                PreparedStatement pstat=con.prepareStatement("update toys set vtoyname=?,mtoyrate=? where ctoyid=?");
                pstat.setString(1,tname.getText());
                pstat.setDouble(2,Double.parseDouble(trate.getText()));
                pstat.setString(3,tid.getText());
                pstat.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Record Updated");
            }
            else if(obj==bsearch)
            {
                PreparedStatement pstat=con.prepareStatement("select ctoyid,vtoyname,mtoyrate from toys where ctoyid=?");
                pstat.setString(1,tid.getText());
                ResultSet res=pstat.executeQuery();
                if(res.next()==true)
                {
                    tname.setText(res.getString(2));
                    trate.setText(res.getString(3));
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Invalid Toy ID");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Help me to get me out of this ? and why i am having this Exception ?

Comment: Make sure to include the proper JDBC library in classpath of your project at runtime as well.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: that's not going to help.  The Sun JDBC-ODBC bridge driver was a standard part of Java on Windows prior to Java 8.

Comment: Do you have Java 8 installed on your system?  The Sun JDBC-ODBC bridge driver isn't part of Java 8, so if your code is actually running in Java 8 then you will get this error.  I haven't seen this error on with Java 7 or earlier on Windows.